# Пунктуация. Тире

Tags: пунктуация

Вместе с платиной поднялись ее геохимические родичи (: или -) никель и хром. (Мих.) Какой здесь поставить лучше знак препинания? Слово "родичи" рассматривать как обобщающее или всё-таки как определяемое слово к приложению "никель и хром"?

Почему в этом предложении ставится тире: Это сегодня новость домашняя, завтра - площадная. (П.)

Comment: Это два разных вопроса, их нужно задавать отдельно.

Comment: «...никель и хром. (Мих.)» ====== Что такое Мих.?

Comment: Это фамилия автора произведения, из которого взята цитата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А. **Вместе с платиной поднялись ее геохимические родичи  ― никель и хром.**

Ставим тире, так как этот знак больше подходит и по семантике, и по интонации.

Семантика: сочетание ***геохимические родичи*** требует **пояснения**, для обобщающего (часто местоименного) слова оно не очень подходит.

Интонация и структура: в конце распространенного  предложения неудобно делать большую пояснительную паузу, характерную для двоеточия, чтобы присоединить два однородных члена. Это скорее присоединительная конструкция.

Б. **Это сегодня новость домашняя, завтра  ― площадная.**

Выбираем тире и паузу в неполном предложении, так как пропущено несколько членов. Пауза обозначит этот пропуск.

Сравнить: **Сегодня эта новость  может быть домашней, а завтра (может быть) площадной.** Здесь можно обйтись без тире.

Comment: "Никель и хром" выступают в роли определения?

Comment: С точки зрения грамматики это два приложения в конце предложения, обособленные с помощью тире.

Comment: Спасибо большое)))